# How does one Klingon recognise another as discommended?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

I'm thinking particularly of the episode "The Mind's Eye" (TNG 4x24). When Picard tells Ambassador Kell that Worf is on the case, Kell interrupts to request another security officer due to Worf's discommendation. ("Worf's discommendation makes that very awkward.")

Kell is from an outlying region of the Empire near the Federation border, so presumably he didn't witness the discommendation firsthand. How then does Kell know about it, if Worf's name is not spoken in the Empire? Presumbly "not spoken" would also extend to the Klingon equivalent of Facebook.

I noticed in the episode ["Sins of the Father"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sins_of_the_Father_(episode)), "Duras then rips Worf's baldric off of him, telling Worf he is unworthy to wear the emblems of their people.", but it's back on again next episode, so it's not that.

I've searched on Memory Alpha and Memory Beta as well as Google but they have nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ambassador is, well, an ambassador, a high ranking legal agent of the government acting as part of its diplomatic interest.

Worf is a person of interest due to his position as a high ranking national in the military service on the flagship of an equally powerful and competing foreign power. A power that the Klingon Empire has contentious dealings with regularly, flipping between enemy and ally often. Worf is not just a regular unknown warrior.

Worf was exiled in public court by the head of the military and government. This at the very least would result in a interdepartmental memo about the discommendment. Especially to the diplomatic agent in charge of dealing with the foreign power, that's related to Worf. Keep in mind that pretty much every Klingon we see on the show are part of the military so would also receive some information.

This is just an example of a typical internal governmental diplomatic communication in action. It would make less sense had the Ambassador not known about Worf's recommendation. You cant represent the government if you dont know what the government's interest are. Diplomats are briefed about any person of interest they are likely to meet on an official meeting. For example, Picard is regularly told about who someone is by Troi before he speaks with them.

Comment: Everybody knows who Worf is. *He Who Must Not Be Named* is probably just called *'that' son of Morg.*

Comment: `The honorless federation petaQ`

Comment: Sorry, could have sworn I accepted this answer already. Better late than never I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly there would have been some form of official announcement/denouncement of the event so that Worf could be 'ignored' by the rest of Klingon society.

The discommendation is a pretty severe **legal** penalty and if you don't tell people about it how would they know?

A sort of *"From this day forward, let it be known.."* type of thing by the Klingon judicial system..with practically instant galactic communications as we see in the Star Trek universe this seems more than possible.

Comment: The legal penalty is the important part, your land and titles are seized and your family is no longer recognised by the Empire, so they'd have no house sigil on them (Worf used to wear the sigil of the House of Mogh on his sash, I believe he even once mentions that it has no meaning as the house no longer exists), or like Worf, they'd continue to wear the emblem of a house that other Klingons could recognised to be shunned. The only unaffiliated Klingon I recall is Alexander, Worf's son, for precisely this reason.